# calling a array element in .Find function

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array with "n" number of strings, i want to call every string in the array in .find function, and search whole sheet for the respective string, then display the position of the string in the worksheet.

```
Dim SCtr as long

Dim whattofind as variant

WhatToFind = Array("pdy", "Pdx", "temp")

For SCtr = LBound(WhatToFind) To UBound(WhatToFind)

     'here is the problem it was searching only first value in the array not going to the next item in the array

    Set Cell = Cells.Find(What:=WhatToFind(SCtr), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                         xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,                  SearchDirection:= _xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
           'do something
Next SCtr
```

which funtion can be used for this purpose or can something be done to make this code work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `End If` in your code. Try the Below code, it will color the cells red where your string in Array is found.

**Try this:**

```
Sub colr()

Dim SCtr As Long
Dim whattofind As Variant
Dim cel As Range


whattofind = Array("pdy", "Pdx", "temp")

For SCtr = LBound(whattofind) To UBound(whattofind)

    Set cel = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=whattofind(SCtr))


    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

Next SCtr

End Sub
```

Try to avoid the Object Names used by Excel. Like `Cell`

Comment: Mikku, thanks man, i didnt find any understandable solution online for this problem,  but you solved it in seconds. works like a charm. Thanks again.